# Is it possible to configure backup filename conventions for Maintenance Plan Wizard in SSMS

Tags: ssms

Is there a way to configure SSMS so that the backup file names for differential backups (created using the Maintenance Plan Wizard) would have the string  "DIFF" in the name?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Ola's scripts.

https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

Not only are they awesome but they will give you the naming convention that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

You can customize the file extension on the Destination tab of the "Define Back Up Database (Differential) Task" step in the wizard. You could use `diff.bak`.

This will result in a maintenance plan that will execute a line something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Foo] TO  DISK = N'K:\MSSQL\Backup\Foo_backup_2019_08_09_163546_1455200.diff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL ...
```